# Google Oauth login keeps redirecting

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a Google Oauth login form. However, when I load it in a particular browser, the `approval_state` keeps changing, and the Google Auth keeps saying "Forwarding..."

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?approval_state=%21ChRJQ1RKLV81aVgtd29r

I'm not really sure why this is occurring or how to debug this, as it doesn't occur in other browsers. Has anyone else ran into this issue and know why this occurs or how to fix it?

[image]

Sometimes after about 50 redirects it will load, but it loads the 'older' version of Google Login -- I can tell this by the style of it.

Comment: I'm seeing this, too (just started today but haven't found anything online beyond this post.)

Comment: A co-worker found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120470722

Comment: @JaredSohn thanks for finding that. Yes it does seem fixed now on Google's end (not seeing this issue anymore, and haven't made any changes to our site's code).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google Cloud Platform..

Go into APIs and Services > Credentials > Edit Your Web Application and download the new Client Secrets (i.e. Download JSON) again and update the file you're currently using with the data in there.

There were new endpoints in my file and swapping this out fixed it.

Hope it does for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding prompt=consent parameter to the link that redirects to google. That parameter fixed it for me and after that regular login without the prompt=consent started working normally too.